# Show that a $\pi_{\leq 1}(S^1)$-module category is equipped with a natural automorphism of identity functor

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

I was given the exercise to show that a $\pi_{\leq 1}(S^1)$ (fundamental groupoid of $S^1$)-module category is equipped with a natural automorphism of identity functor.

If $C$ is such a category, I need to produce an isomorphism $A \to A$ for every $A \in C$. My idea is to consider the isomorphism, for any $e^{i\theta}$ an object of $\pi_{\leq 1}(S^1)$,
$$
A \mapsto (e^{i\theta}\triangleright A) \mapsto e^{-i\theta}\triangleright(e^{i\theta}\triangleright A) \cong (e^{-i\theta}\otimes e^{i\theta})\triangleright A = e^0\triangleright A\cong A
$$
by the axioms of a module category, and I would then check naturality as well. But because this works for any $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, I instead have a family of natural automorphisms. Technically this fulfills the requirement of the task, but the wording makes it seem as if there should be some canonical natural automorphism, which it appears I have not found.

Q: i) Does what I wrote down describe a natural automorphism of identity functor?
ii) If so, is it what the question intends for, or is there something else more canonical?

Comment: How did you get the morphism $A \mapsto (e^{i\theta}  \triangleright A)$, in general?

Comment: @JHF oh shoot I guess there is no such morphism. maybe i'm completely off base then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $1 \in S^1$ be the basepoint, and let $\gamma$ be a path that starts at $1$, wraps around the circle once, and ends back at $1$.  Then, it seems that the natural automorphism you want is $$A \xleftarrow{\cong} 1 \triangleright A \xrightarrow{\gamma \triangleright \mathrm{id}} 1 \triangleright A \xrightarrow{\cong} A.$$  The inverse map is given by the same construction, but with the reversed path $\bar{\gamma}$ in place of $\gamma$.  Furthermore, naturality follows from the naturality of $1 \triangleright (-)$ and the fact $$(\mathrm{id} \triangleright f) \circ (\gamma \triangleright \mathrm{id}) = \gamma \triangleright f = (\gamma \triangleright \mathrm{id}) \circ (\mathrm{id} \triangleright f)$$ for any morphism $f$.

Comment: Okay, so the morphism $1\triangleright A \to 1\triangleright A$ is given by functoriality of $(-)\triangleright A$ on $\gamma: 1 \to 1$